# What happens if the lock object is changed in synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading

What will happen if we modify the lock object inside synchronized block ? 
I think the synchronization will fail and any thread can enter the synchronization block . But when i run the program , the synchronization is still intact . why ?

```
 synchronized(obj)
  {
   System.out.println("1 " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
   obj = new Object();
   System.out.println("2 " +Thread.currentThread().getId());
  }
```

Here's is the link of complete program

http://www.javaroots.com/2015/01/java-multithreading-interview-question.html

Comment: each thread which enters the block could be locking on a different object and almost certainly a bug.  Generally speaking you should only lock on final fields.

Comment: yes . but this lock should not work once thread one executes the second line . but surprisingly , it is working . after line 2 , thread 2 still waiting .

Comment: NOTE:  Your example does not "modify the lock object."  It creates a _new_ object and updates the `obj` variable to refer to the new object.  The old object still exists, and the thread still has it locked at that point, but a different thread that tries to execute the same block of code will synchronize on the new object.

Comment: While another thread might see the new object and lock it instead, there is no guarantee that it will. It might see the old object and attempt to lock the same object.  Once a thread starts waiting to obtain a lock on an object it will continue to wait on that object even if the reference is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't change the object, you just created a new object and told the compiler that you will name it "obj" (so "obj" no longer refers to your original object), so every modification to "obj" will affect the newly created object.